# Rivers A and B unite, to form a new River, C. We measure the flow in A (300 L/s, SD=5 L/s) and C (320 L/s, SD=5/s). Corr(A,C) = -0.5. SD(B)?

Tags: correlation, standard-deviation

How can I calculate the Standard deviation of my estimate for the river B, as my estimation is
B = C - A, and C and A correlate negatively (-0.5)?

Comment: Convert the correlation to a covariance and apply [the formula for a sum of covariances](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/346327/intuition-behind-the-formula-for-the-variance-of-a-sum-of-two-variables).

Comment: σ^2(x-y) = σ^2(x)+σ^2(y)-2*ρ*σ(x)*σ(y).                                                                                             σ^2(x-y) = (25 + 25 - 2 * -0.5  * 5 * 5 )  L^2 / s^2                                                                           =75 L^2 / s^2, SD = 8.66 L / s (just like in the solution) Thank you!!